# CMD compare variable with list item

Tags: window, cmd

I need help with CMD scripts. Here is my problem:

I have list of items, also I have variable which show for example current version of SDK.

```
set CURRENT_VERSION = 2.3
set LIST_OF_ITEMS   = (4.0.3 2.3.3 2.2)
```

I want to write something like this

```
for %%A in %CURRENT_VERSION % do (
    if [%%A] grt [%SDK_VERSION%] (
        echo greater. 
    )
)
```

Also I want to now what must I write to `break` or `continue` in for.

Comment: CMD scripts are for Windows and are totally unrelated to Android / bash scripts don't have anything like that syntax. What exactly are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is almost the same you wrote, but it works.

```
set CURRENT_VERSION=2.3
set LIST_OF_ITEMS=4.0.3 2.3.3 2.2

for %%A in (%LIST_OF_ITEMS%) do (
    if [%%A] gtr [%CURRENT_VERSION%] (
        echo greater.
        goto continue
    )
)
:continue
```

However, I think the comparison is done in reversed order, so it should be:

```
set CURRENT_VERSION=2.3
set LIST_OF_ITEMS=4.0.3 2.3.3 2.2

for %%A in (%LIST_OF_ITEMS%) do (
    if [%CURRENT_VERSION%] gtr [%%A] (
        echo Current version greater %%A.
        goto continue
    )
)
echo Current version too low
goto :EOF

:continue
```

Note that version numbers are compared *like strings*. If you want to have right results with these numbers, then they both must have the same format; that is:

```
set CURRENT_VERSION=2.3.0
```